# How to Diff Entire Org (list of changed files) in VSCode?

Tags: vs-code, visualstudiocode, diff

When right clicking on the `force-app\main\default` folder and clicking `SFDX: Diff Folder Against Org` it doesn't list all the files changed in all the subfolders, but some changed files are not listed.

I believe it happens when I have classes in subfolders which are inside subfolders locally, but when deploying they are all in the same folder.

How do I retrieve a list of all the Org Differences in the `Org differences` tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used that VS Code / SFDX feature, but here is what I usually do -

1. Create a local git repository if you don't already have one (`git init`)
2. Commit the latest changes
3. Set your package.xml file to contain the code/metadata you want to compare
4. Right click on package.xml and "Retrieve Source in Manifest From Org"
5. Use the source control tab in VS Code to see the differences

Then if you want to roll back, just discard all pending changes in the source control tab.

I use this technique to find differences between flows, objects/fields, sharing rules, etc. all the time.

There is a good VS Code extension to help you set your package.xml file called "Salesforce Package.xml Generator Extension for VS Code" as well.

Comment: So how does it work? Does the Source Control differences with the Salesforce Org replace the differences with the Git repository?

Comment: Because I use both :)

Comment: @Z0q I'm not fully understanding your question. Git is a version control software. When working with git, you can view a diff between your last commit and your current files. If your latest changes are committed, nothing should be replaced. You could always retrieve your orgs code in a different git branch.

Comment: I'm finally understanding your approach, thank you very much!